# Postgresql 12 - Simple select statement without filter condition is giving less throughput of 5K rows/sec? What can we optimize here?

Tags: postgresql, performance

I am trying to read about 4.5 to 5 million record table without any filter conditions..
  I just need only two to three columns (varchar) from a table in postgres12 version..
  The table contains just 20 columns (most are varchar)
  So, my query goes like this.

```
SELECT
    id as INDIV_ID,
    loc 
FROM
    table
```

Explain plan output:

```
pgres=> explain (analyze, buffers, timing, format text) SELECT id as INDIV_ID, org_ext_loc FROM individuals;
                                                        QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on individuals  (cost=0.00..353469.48 rows=4869048 width=54) (actual time=0.017..2659.760 rows=4869591 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=2133 read=302646
 Planning Time: 0.814 ms
 Execution Time: 3092.984 ms
(4 rows)
```

explain plan output with track_io_timing = ON

```
                                                        QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on individuals  (cost=0.00..353469.48 rows=4869048 width=54) (actual time=0.019..2607.686 rows=4869591 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared read=304779
 Planning Time: 2.975 ms
 Execution Time: 3034.370 ms
(4 rows)
```

Our server information:

```
OS : Oracle Linux 7.3
RAM : 65707 MB
HDD Capacity : 2 Terabytes
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                16
CPU MHz:               2294.614
```

I tried various approaches of using

- table partitioning with range on(another sequence column)
- using parallel hints
- SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather TO 8;

Quite vexed with the exhaustive search & without proper results & throughput is really down to 5K rows/sec.

I am using pentaho(kettle) etl tool to run this query through jdbc connectivity on server.

My postgres12 server is on same machine as the pentaho

I tried creating table in two ways

- Normally without any partitions
- Using range partitioning

But still the retrieval times are very high..

What can I do to get throughput of about 15K rows/sec?

Answer (score 1):

The execution plan says that the query returns the 5 million rows in 3 seconds.

If you see worse performance on the client end, it must either be the network or the client software that's limiting you.

Comment: The client software in this case is pentaho (ETL tool) resides in the same machine & if you have any idea on this pentaho, pls point it out.. thanks & much appreciate it

Comment: Hm, doesn't look like `track_io_timing` is `on`, at least I see no I/O times. Don't try finding the problem on the database end, it must be elsewhere. Profile the whole process!